# Does pyspark configuration in jupyter aplly to all the notebooks combined or for each individual notebook

Tags: pyspark

If i use the max executors config to 25 while starting a jupyter notebook using pyspark command. does this max executors limit apply to all of my notebooks combined or for each notebook?